# Is every "vectors" of STL deque's implementation always has the same size?

Tags: c++, stl, deque

I have read The C++standard Library A Tutorial and reference 2nd, it said that deque's implementation include many blocks, I was curious that if i insert a element in the middle of the deque, will all the elements after the new inserted elements be moved backward just like vector,Or it will only move the elements in the inserted block?

Comment: The standard doesn't prescribe such details. If you are interested in how a particular implementation works, study its source code - they all come with it. The standard does say that `insert()` in the middle invalidates all iterators, pointers and references to all elements in the `deque`

Comment: It'll move either all the following or all the preceding elements, depending which side is shorter.

Comment: Don't insert into the middle of a queue to begin with; you've most likely picked the wrong data structure for the task.

Comment: There are lots of requirements on a deque that limits the implementation freedom. One is that random access has to be `O(1)`, which more or less requires that the middle blocks are always full (so you don't have to scan for empty positions).

Answer (score 1):

As Igor said, the standard doesn't mention such details. However, given that it *does* say that all pointers, iterators and references are invalidated, I think you can assume that it moves more than the elements in a single "block".

As an aside, given the iterator requirements for `deque`, all the blocks (except the first and the last one) have to be kept full. Random access iterators require constant time "increment by `N`", and that can't be done if you have to count how many items are in each block (or, at least, I don't see a way to do that).  So that would imply that all the elements either before or after the insertion point have to be moved. (again, not just the ones in the same "block")